# Understanding of increments in factorial algorithms

Tags: increment, factorial

So I just started my first year at University doing computer science. I have a question regarding some of the functionality in a factorial algorithm in java. I have gotten my factorial counter to work(using a for loop), however if the algorithm tries to count the factorial for more than one number during execution the factorial it increments some how? I was wondering how this works? I have had an idea to implement it in a menu system of some sort for personal purposes, I wonder if there is some way to make the algorithm more viable. This is the code I have got so far(Note that the IDE is blueJ(I know it is horrible but its for uni) Thanks for the support!

```
public int CalculateFactorial(int n){

    for(int i=1; i<= n; i++){
        factorial = factorial * i;
    }

    return factorial;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given I cannot see the variable `factorial` in your code sample I'm assuming it's a global/class variable? Try declaring it locally.

Comment: BTW factorial is the classic recursion example rather than using a loop.